# How to get the parent tag using selector?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, css-selectors

Is there any way in css selector using which i can parse the `parent` tag name which is in this case `tr`.

Here is the elements for the search:

```
html_content="""
<tr>
    <td>Hi!!!!</td>
</tr>
"""
```

If i consider the above element, what should be the css selector to parse the parent name `tr`?

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
root = fromstring(html_content)
item = root.cssselect("td")[0].text
print(item)
```

Comment: Have you using considered using `beautifulsoup` ? It has a built in `parent` tag.

Comment: Yep I like to use `BeautifulSoup` as well and i know there is an option there. However, it doesn't support psudoelement search pattern, as in `:contains()` so, i like to stick to lxml library. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is a syntax like

```
*:has(>td)
```

which is not supported by `lxml.html` yet

You can solve the issue with built-in `getparent()` method

```
item = root.cssselect("td")[0]
print(item.getparent().tag)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `lxml.html.HtmlElement.xpath()` method:

```
import lxml.html

html_content="""
<tr>
    <td>Hi!!!!</td>
</tr>
"""

root = lxml.html.fromstring(html_content)
item = root.xpath("td/..")[0]

print(item.tag)  # tr
```

---

- `td/..` - xpath expression, `..` refers to the parent node